# ctrl+alt+arrow suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> a lot. Suddenly the arrow key gets swallowed when I enter this shortcut. I tried in multiple programs. I am using RDP right now and know about the settings but it has been working until now what suddenly changed?

**Edit**
All the above keys work when they are not combined, including <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+any other key. e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> works. I am using a dell inspiron laptop RDP to a dell inspiron desktop. Os: windows 10

**Update**
I am now at the desktop computer with no RDP and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> is working. So it has something to do with RDP. I still don't know what.

Comment: I assume that you've verified that the arrow keys are working by themselves, and that Ctrl and Alt work with other keys? Also, what kind of computer, what kind of keyboard, and what operating system?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.